# Dataset.read throws heap error in mahout

Tags: out-of-memory, mahout

This is my java code.

```
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
            "/home/689693/Desktop/sunitha/customer360/churn/test/test.csv"));
    DataInput dataInput = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

    Dataset dataSet = Dataset.read(dataInput);

    Data data = new Data(dataSet);
    System.out.println(data.size());
```

This throws

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.data.Dataset.readFields(Dataset.java:316)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.data.Dataset.read(Dataset.java:309)
at com.tcs.test.MahoutExample.main(MahoutExample.java:26)
```

Comment: What are your machine specs? And how big is your data set?

Comment: My JVM Specification is                                             Current heap size: 
 44,889 kbytes
Maximum heap size: 
418,752 kbytes                                                              data set is very small...a few KBs..